# what's the difference between two Python imports

Tags: python, import

Python [has](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) two ways to import something from a module:

```
from mymodule import ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree
```

and

```
from mymodule import (ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree)
```

I cannot find any note (probably, I'm just not trying hard enough) on this in Python's documentation. I want to know the significant difference between these two ways of importing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you put the items to import between brackets, you can use more than one line for everything you want to import, without escaping newlines.

Comment: And that's it? I hoped it would be something more interesting :) Anyway, thanks.